# Ant Design disabling date before today and other custom date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am currently using ant design for my react project and having trouble with the Datepicker module. I want to disable past dates and some more, I want to disable some of the future dates as well. Let's say I wanted to disable 2020-10-29 when I add in as follows, it blocked all of the dates.  Below is my Date picker module.

```
<DatePicker
   style= {{width: '100%'}}
   onChange = {this.handlePickupDate}
   placeHolder = "Select Delivery Date"
   disabledDate  = { 
       d => !d
         || d.isBefore(currentDate)
         || current < moment().endOf('day')
         || moment('2020-10-29')

   }
/>
```

if I add in `moment("2020-10-29")`, it blocked all the date as the following screenshot

[image]

Without it is , it looks fine

[image]

So let's say i would like to block 2020-10-29,  2020-10-29 and 2020-10-30 (technically these values will come from api) how can i block each individual date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future references, this is the answer

```
let blockDate = ['2020-10-23', '2020-10-28'];

<DatePicker
    style={{width: '100%'}}
    onChange={this.handlePickupDate}
    placeHolder="Select Delivery Pickup Date"
    disabledDate={ d => !d
                       || d.isBefore(currentDate)
                       || currentDate < moment().endOf('day')
       || blockDate.findIndex(date=>date===moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) !== -1}
/>
```